# Can this system design beign improved?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am a new user of NoSQL, and I want to know if this idea is a pro gamer move or a newbie error?

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

I am designing that uses firebase storage to manage the data, what it does is allow the registered users to upload images to different items, such as, mountains, food, home, etc on different topics,
so you go into one of those topics and upload an image related to that, so when other users go to the section (mountains, food, home, etc), can visualize what has been uploaded.

**THE PROBLEM**

As long as I have seen, a user cannot store an image with an unique ID, so there will be overrides

**THE "SOLUTION"**

A user can hold a collection of items with uniques IDs, So when a user Uploads an image to a topic like Food the images storages in their own collection with a TAG of the topic, and also the Id of the users will be saved in a file. So when other users look at the section of Food, the algorithm will look at the users who uploaded the photo then look at their collection of images in search of the Tag, and retrieve that image.

So another issue could be that there will be a lot of users to search on, So it crossed my mind to create folders, that contain all users that have the same 3 initial letters. So it will make the easier search.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to make this thing better?

Any documentation or guide will help a lot

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when a user uploads an image to a topic like Food the images storages in their own collection with a TAG of the topic and also the Id of the users will be saved in a file.

Yes, that's a common practice.

> So when other users look at the section of Food, the algorithm will look at the users who uploaded the photo then look at their collection of images in search of the Tag and retrieve that image.

Sounds good. In code should look like this:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("photos").whereEqualTo("tag", "food")
```

> Is there any way to make this thing better?

No, you found the simplest and easiest solution.

Comment: Really apreciatte your answer! I got one little more question do you know how the algoritm of this Services (FireBase Auth) works? When an users log in, (if all users are Id are in the same path), it just have to check one by one, to see if there is a match?

Comment: I cant vote up at the moment, Alex, I really wish i could EDIT: Ok there it goes my vote